# What’s the best sequence to laminate this floor plan?

Tags: laminate-floor

Laying laminate over a subfloor.
Refer diagram - A. Is short passageway after bottom of stairs landing. B is bathroom.
My assumption is to start at B and work out the door to the passageway and then backwards to A, just because probably easier to work backwards with a smaller workspace?

EDIT - I can’t start at the bottom as I have another doorway/room which is occupied. the intent is to complete the space in the diagram and move everything over and work on the other room.

[image]

Comment: where  can you start? A and B are not good places to start.

Answer (score 0):

start against the longest edge, that would be the bottom of the diagram.

Comment: I should have told the whole story. I’ be edited above. I have another room which is occupied, so I have to start at the top of the diagram and work down.